# How to deal with columns containing commas while using comma as field terminator

Tags: csv, azure-synapse, external-tables

I am creating an external table in Synapse serverless pool using data stored in a CSV file. I am using file format as DELIMITEDTEXT with Field Terminator as ",". Now one of my columns has values that have comma within themselves as well, so how do I deal with this ?

To specify, the column is called Description and contains message body from emails so there are commas present within the value.

I wasn't able to understand how to do this, as solutions recommend either enclosing the values within double quotes or using a different delimiter in the file itself. But I cannot change the source file.

Is it possible to create a data flow to replace the commas in a column value with spaces ?

Comment: If you have Quote character, you can define them while creating external file format. `CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat1] 
 WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT ,
        FORMAT_OPTIONS (
    FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
    STRING_DELIMITER='"',
    USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE
   ))`. String_delimiter is used for defining the quote character.

Comment: If you dont have quote character surrounded in each value, we can solve this using dataflow also.

Comment: by quote character do you mean whether the values in the description are enclosed in double quotes ? If so, no I don't have those !

How would we use dataflow to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have quote character in your csv file, you can define them while creating external file format.

```sql
 CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat1]
 WITH (
  FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT , 
  FORMAT_OPTIONS ( FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
  STRING_DELIMITER='"',
  USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE ))
```

**String_delimiter** is used for defining the quote character.

When you don't have Quote character in your file, then you need to use dataflow to remove the `,` from description column. Below is the dataflow approach.

**Sample data used in this dataflow:**

```
id,stockplace,stock,id_rep,description
1,A-100,40,1,asw,asw
1,B-100,10,1,aa
1,C-100,5,1,aa
2,A-300,90,2,s
```

In this input data, we need to remove the comma in description.

1. Take the  `source`  transformation and read the input data with different delimiter other than comma `,` . So that all columns are treated as single column.

[image]

2. Take the   `derive`  transformation and extract the first few columns (except description) from the input data and output them as a new column called  `left_col`.

**Expression for left_Col:**
`substringIndex({id,stockplace,stock,id_rep,description},',' , 4)`

[image]

3. Take another   `derive`  transformation and replace commas with spaces.
   **Expression**:
   `concat(left_col,',',replace(dropLeft({id,stockplace,stock,id_rep,description},length(left_col)+1),',',' '))`

This will remove the comma and replaces with space.

4. Take the  `select`  transformation to select only the required columns. Remove all the columns that are computed and used temporarily. In this case, except column `left_col` all are selected. As `left_col` is created as temporary column to remove all the extra commas in the original column

[image]

5. Take the  `parse`  transformation and parse the output of the  `select`  transformation as a delimited file with a comma as the column delimiter. Then take the sink transformation and output the data to a file.

[image]

Comment: Take the select transformation to select only the required columns. Remove all the columns that are computed and used temporarily.

I wasn't able to understand this part clearly.

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope u understood now.